# Installing Android SQLite Asset Helper

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I need to use my ready made database. Search for solution on internet did not work until I decided I will use the mentioned library found [here](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). However, I found it hard to use the library in that installation procedures are really shallow for beginners.

I will appreciate a step by step procedure on how to use it with Android Studio. In my struggle I tried copying sources to main/libs and adding the line to gradle did not work. I use API 19 if that helps.

**UPDATE** 
here is my build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
        compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

trying to compile the project I get error
`Error:(9, 0) No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+]
Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)`

Comment: "Using it by copying sources to main/libs" -- where in the instructions is there any reference to a "main/libs"?

Comment: that was my trial after I got lost. I did not say that come from docs. So would you be kind enough to help me?

Comment: Are you aware that Android Studio is using Gradle and you should be following the instructions for Gradle users?

Comment: Year, the first thing I have no idea is where do I extract sources I downloaded to?

Comment: You are welcome to explain what problems you encountered when following [the instructions](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), and perhaps somebody can help you with those problems. Basically, add `mavenCentral()` to `repositories` in `build.gradle` if it is not already there. Add his `compile` line to your `depedencies` in `build.gradle`. Put your database in `assets/databases/` (in a ZIP file if you are supporting older devices). Extend his `SQLiteAssetHelper` much like you would extend `SQLiteOpenHelper`, just without your own `onCreate()`. And that should be about it.

Comment: "Year, the first thing I have no idea is where do I extract sources I downloaded to?" -- delete those sources, unless you plan to be *changing* `SQLiteAssetHelper` (instead of *using* `SQLiteAssetHelper`).

Comment: Cool, I have updated whats happening now. I think am almost there.

Comment: The `compile` directive goes in `dependencies` at the root level, not the `dependencies` within `buildscript`. The `dependencies` inside `buildscript` are for compile-time tools.

Comment: do you mean something like below or just adding the line at the bottom?
`allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    }
}`

Comment: I have read gradle manual on this but I keep getting error below
```
Error:(22, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'compile()'!

Possible causes could be:  
  - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent ( Fix Gradle settings )
  - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method ( Apply Gradle plugin )
  - or there is a mistake in a build script ( Goto source )
``

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but it doesn't seem to have a proper answer, and I found it while trying to install `SQLiteAssetHelper` myself, so I thought I should share my experience, according to the instructions found [here](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/issues/94).

Like most inexperienced Android Studio users, **I thought I should `Download ZIP` from the [GitHub](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/issues/94) repository and place it somewhere in my PC**. Turns out **this is not the way to *Install SQLiteAssetHelper***, if you are using `Gradle` which is a Build system integrated in Android Studio.

What you need to do is simply described in the [GitHub](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/issues/94) repository [Setup](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper#setup) section. So here is a Step-by-step guide, with some additional information:

1) Make sure that your `Gradle` is not in `Offline Mode`. (In Android Studio *which is currently at version 2.2.2*, go to `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Development > Gradle` and uncheck `Offline Work` in case that is checked. *(This is only required for your first Sync)*

2) In your Android Studio Project Navigator (on the left) you should see an item entitled `Gradle Scripts`. Expand it, and you should find a `build.gradle` file. If you see two such files, there should be a comment in a parenthesis next to each one saying `Project: YourProjectName` and `Module: App`.

If you open the one saying `Project: YourProjectName` you should see the following comments:

```
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
```

So, you should choose the one saying `Module: App`, at the end of which you should see something like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  ...
}
```

At that point, you should just add the code pointed out in [GitHub](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/issues/94), like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  ...
}
```

That's all. To start using it, you just have to extend the `SQLiteAssetHelper` class, pretty much like extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Comment: By the way, Android Studio suggests not to use + in version numbers. So I switched to using `com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1`