# implement 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+' is not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-dependencies

I have occurred the above mentioned error and I could not found any answer from internet as well as several books. If any one can give me a solution, it will be very help for me for make my `SQLite database`

1) I changed the word of 'implementation' instead of 'compiler' not success,
2) I changed it as implementation `'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'`, but it also unsuccess

```
implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
```

I found that error, Unable to resolve dependency for `':app@debug/compileClasspath':` Could not resolve `com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+.`

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479755/installing-android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `build.gradle` file in the root of your project check in the `allprojects` block check if `mavenCentral()` is present:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() ... possibly others
        mavenCentral() // Important
    }
}
```

This is because the library you are trying to download is hosted there.